# Tower of Hanoi solution in Concrete Mathematics

Tags: proof-verification, recurrence-relations

I'm working through [Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025) and have some trouble following a proof about the number of steps needed to solve the 3 peg Tower of Hanoi problem.

For reference, this is the relevant text

[image]

They make a point about about explaining why $T_n \ge 2T_{n-1} + 1$, but I don't see why this is valid as $T_n$ has been defined as the *minimum number of moves*, so I don't see

- when $T_n \gt 2T_{n-1} + 1$ is ever a valid solution as you already know $T_n = 2T_{n-1} + 1$ is a valid solution,
- why you can't conclude that $T_n = 2T_{n-1} + 1$ from this part of the proof alone (or, why is the $T_n \le 2T_{n-1} + 1$ part of the proof necessary).

Comment: You have to prove that you can do it in so-and-so moves (first part), and you have to prove that you cannot do it any better (second part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They make a point about about explaining why $T_n \ge 2T_{n-1} + 1$, but I don't see why this is valid as $T_n$ has been defined as the *minimum number of moves*, so I don't see
>
> - when $T_n \gt 2T_{n-1} + 1$ is ever a valid solution as you already know $T_n = 2T_{n-1} + 1$ is a valid solution,

Yes, you already know from part I that $T_n \le 2T_{n-1} + 1$.  But, you have to look at part II as a stand-alone argument, i.e. treat it as if you *didn't* already know that $T_n = 2T_{n-1} + 1$ is a valid solution. So, since part II, *by itself* merely shows that it is impossible that $T_n < 2T_{n-1} + 1$, part II of the proof merely shows that $T_n \geq 2T_{n-1} + 1$

> - why you can't conclude that $T_n = 2T_{n-1} + 1$ from this part of the proof alone (or, why is the $T_n \le 2T_{n-1} + 1$ part of the proof necessary).

Good question!  Yes, it seems that part II of the proof gives us a recipe that shows that $T_n = 2T_{n-1} + 1$: move the pile that is on top of the largest disk to the peg that is *the other one* from the target peg , then move the largest disk to its target peg, and finally move the pile on top of that, giving exactly $2T_{n-1} + 1$.

However, what the proof is really saying here, is this. *In order to* get to the solution, *at some point* you have to move the largest disk to the target peg. And, a little thought shows that that is only possible when all the other disks are on the 'other' peg, i.e. neither on the peg where the largest disk is, nor the target peg. So, if there is any solution at all, then it will *have to* involve the following actions, and *in that order*:

1) First, the $n-1$ pile needs to be moved away from the largest disk. Since they are on the largest disk at the start, that means that you need to move them all ... and they have to end up as a pile, since they all need to be on the 'other' peg in order for the following action to be possible:

2) The largest peg needs to be moved from wherever it is to the target peg

3) Finally, the $n-1$ pile needs to be moved from the other peg to the target peg.

Note that the *order* is important here .. we can;t somehow save moves by doing things that somehow, at the same time, accomplish what needs to be done for part 1, as well as for part 3. No, first *all* of part 1) needs to be completed, then part 2) can be done, and only then part 3) can be completed. So, the minimum number of moves for the whole thing is, at a minimum, the minimum number of moves for 1), plus the minimum number of moves for part 2), plus the minimum number of moves for part 3).

OK, but it all still seems so very obvious that you *can* do part 1) in exactly $T_{n-1}$ moves, and same for part 3), and part 2) should only take 1 move.  Right?

Well, think about this:  we assumed by inductive hypothesis that moving $n-1$ disks from one peg to another takes $T_{n-1}$ moves *where there are no other disks involved*.  Now, however, we have an extra disk. So: might the presence of this extra disk prevent one to move the pile in $T_{n-1}$ moves?  Might the presence of this disk somehow necessarily increase that number of moves of that action (or: possibly prevent this action from being possible at all?) Now, *that*, of course, is the province of part I of the proof, not part II. And this is why part I of the proof is necessary.

Now, I have to say, the text does not discuss this possibility at all .. which is also why I am actually quite sympathetic to your second question: what is part I of the proof even saying that part II of the proof isn't already pointing out? Well, a proper proof for part I would have to point out that the presence of the extra disk does *not* in any way hinder the movement of the pile, and that, *therefore*, moving the pile *can* indeed still be done in $T_{n-1}$ moves.

Anyway, the point is: part II of the proof only points out that parts 1) and 3) take *at least* $T_{n-1}$ moves, and it is up to part I of the proof to point out that in fact each can be done in *exactly* $T_{n-1}$ moves.

Likewise, part II of the proof *by itself* does not make it clear that part 2) of the necessary actions (moving the largest disk from start to goal post) can be done in exactly 1 step.  Of course, it is blatantly obvious that it *is* possible, as long as action 1) consistent of moving gthe pile to the peg other than both the start and goal peg, but actually I think the text does a decent job here, in pointing out that possible it does take more than 1 move ("we might move the argest disk more than once, if we're not too alert"). Indeed, action 1) never specifies that the pile *should* go to the other peg ... it just said that it needs to moved so that the largest disk can possibly move itself. And, if you were to move the pile to the goal peg, then you can only move the largest disk to the other peg, and hence it is still not on the goal peg, and so it would take more than 1 move to get the largest disk from the start peg to the goal peg (again, I do agree that the text could have spelled this all out a bit more).

So again, part II of the proof sates that action 2) takes *at a minimum* 1 move, and we *need* part I of the proof to point out that we *can* move the largest disk from start to goal disk in exactly one move.

Comment: Yes, I understand the necessity of proving that you cannot do it in less than $2T_{n-1} + 1$ moves. I just don't understand why you cannot conclude from that second part that the minimum amount of moves will never be greater than $2T_{n-1} + 1$.

Comment: @Freek OK, I see. I think the crucial phrase is "We might move the largest disk more than once, if we're not too alert.". Now,  obviously, if move the largest disk more than once, you end up with more than $2T_{n-1}+1$ moves, and this is why they end up concluding that the minimum number is *at least* that many moves, rather than exactly that many. But, I think i now see your confusion, because you would just say "Well, if we *are* alert, and are smart about this, then we do move the largest disk just exactly once".  ...(continued)

Comment: @Freek So, I guess the crucial quesrion is: is it clear, in the second part of the proof, that you can always solve the puzzle by moving the largest disk just once? Well .... you would probably say yes: just move the $n-1$ pile to the peg where the largest disk should not go, now move the largest disk to the peg it should go, and now move the pile on top of the largest disk. The thing is, in specifying all that, you are back to the first part of the proof. The second part, as is, does not specify that, and so it is not clear that you can solve the puzzle by moving the largest disk just once.

Comment: Thanks. I personally don't read the first part as a proof for the strategy, only a proof for an upper limit for $T_n$. AFAICT this fact isn't really used in the second part, so if the strategy would've been reiterated in the second part (which it arguably is), that part would stand on its own.

Comment: @Freek Now that I have a better idea as to what your question is, I have completely rewritten my Answer. Hopefully this will better address your question.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Considering the "influence" of an extra disc or discs, and pointing out that that is what part 1 provided me with some valuable new insight. However, I think in the second part it _is_ implied that that you can move the $n - 1$ discs to another peg given the "extra" disc. If it's not, how can we say (at least) $T_{n-1}$ steps are needed to move the $n - 1$ to the "other" peg? For me, this means the second part does *not* stand on its own anyway.

Comment: @Freek When you say that something is *needed*, you are not implying that it is possible. I could say that in order to go to Alpha Centauri within a year I *need* to go faster than the speed of light ... but I don't imply that this is possible. Same here: all they do in part II is point out that in order for the larger disk to move from goal to target, you *need* to move the pile first. So, maybe it is not possible ... or maybe it is possible, but it takes more than $T_{n-1}$ moves .. but what is *definitely* true is that you *cannot* do it in less than $T_{n-1}$

Comment: I think the missing part was that getting to the initial situation with $n - 1$ discs on the "other" pile took *at least* $T_{n-1}$ steps. This makes sense to me, as we don't make any assumptions how we got in that situation. Furthermore, we _can_ take the second and third steps to be $1$ and $T_{n-1}$ moves, but it's still a lower bound since we don't know how we ended up in the initial situation.

Comment: @Freek Right!  And again, it's *at least* because of potential things like the possible 'interference' of the extra largest disk.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be having a problem with the very meaning of the symbol $\geq$.

It doesn't mean that any situation could occur in practice ($>$ or $=$), it simply asserts that situation $<$ cannot occur.

When we write $$T_n \geq 2T_{n-1} + 1$$ with $T_n$ being defined as the minimum number of moves to achieve some Task, we simply mean that it's impossible to achieve given Task in a smaller number of moves.

Similarly when we write $$T_n \leq 2T_{n-1} + 1$$ we mean that there is a way to achieve given Task in a number of moves no greater than $2T_{n-1} + 1$.

When both of these hold, then the exact minimal number of moves required is $2T_{n-1} + 1$.

Comment: Yes, this all makes sense to me. However, what I don't understand is why you can't derive $T_n = 2T_{n-1} + 1$ from the explanation given in the second part. It talks about "at least $T_{n-1}$ moves", and "move the largest disk more than once", but why wouldn't contraining that to $T_{n-1}$ moves, move largest disk once, and again do the $T_{n-1}$ moves suffice to prove $T_n = 2T_{n-1} + 1$. Or, to put it a different way: where does the $\gt$ originate from in second part of the proof.

Comment: @Freek It looks like you would like to prove that $T_n \leq 2T_{n-1} + 1$ in one go, just like instead of focusing first on $\implies$ and then $\Leftarrow$ you can sometimes prove $\Leftrightarrow$ in one go. The problem here is that there is no natural way to phrase such a direct proof, not even here but in any case. To prove that $T_n$ is the minimum number of moves to achieve your Task, the only natural thing to do is the two step proof that I described, and so no matter what the task is.

Comment: (continuation) @Freek You may have the impression that you're repeating yourself in the two steps, and in a way the two steps are indeed similar here, but English doesn't have a syntaxical way to phrase both in the same sentence. You're always going to end up saying two things and splitting the proof into two steps.

Comment: I just feel that the second part already says that there is a valid solution for $2T_{n-1} + 1$ steps (by moving the smaller piles 2 times, and 1 time for the larger disc). Given the fact that we're looking for the minimum amount of steps, this would imply to me that $T_n = 2T_{n-1} + 1$. Can you point out why that isn't the case?

Comment: @Freek That's because the second part says "to achieve your Task, you need to do this *at some point*, and also this *at some point*, and that *at some point*, and the costs of each part add up and you get a lower bound", BUT it [the second part] is totally oblivious of the fact that, put together, these three necessary steps actually make up a valid solution.

Comment: Ah, upon re-reading it for the nth time, I see the "and it has taken *at least* $T_{n-1}$ moves" phrase in the second part. I think this explains it to me. I don't follow the "actually make up a valid solution" reasoning, it's quite the point of this part to sketch a valid solution, right?

Comment: @Freek No, it's not even *trying* to sketch a valid solution, that's the point, it's only pointing out some pieces that will have to be part of any valid solution somehow, but without even considering whether there is a valid solution at all out there.

Comment: I think we're not in disagreement here, just using different terms. Thanks for all the help!